# Jhipster is not generating application with angular 2

Tags: jhipster

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6RxZ.png)

I'm starting jhipster and creating my first project. But I would like to create a project with angular 2 and verified in your stack that it would be possible. However, following the steps https://jhipster.github.io/installation/ is not possible with the ANGULAR 2. What could be happening?

Comment: Angular 4 is the replacement for 2 in jhipster. 4 is very similar to 2

Answer (score 1):

JHipster generates an application using either AngularJS or Angular for the frontend.

**AngularJS** refers to v1, while **Angular** refers to all versions greater than v1.  The latest version of Angular is v4, so that is what the project is generated with.

The major differences between Angular 2 and Angular 4 include performance improvements, and the animations package was extracted from `@angular/core` to  `@angular/platform-browser/animations`